# Apache2 Alternate SSL Port

Tags: apache2, ssl, reverse-proxy

I am unable to use port 443 in my reverse proxy because ATT Uverse automatically allocates this port to its WAP. Is there any way for me to dictate an alternative port and have my reverse proxy automatically refer to the new port just as it would if it were port 443? I know there is a way to change the port and then when typing in the address you would type https://youradress.com/port/example or something of that nature, but is there a way to do this without having to dictate the secure port in the address?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, but if you're asking, can you have a service listen on a different port and have a browser connect to https: and it look to any other port than 443, no, it doesn't work that way.  A browser, expects either port 80, or 443, unless specified in the address.

Comment: So in the reverse proxy, I can't add a rewrite with the different port for this to happen automatically?

Comment: You can forward any port to any port, depending on the proxy.  However, if you want your client to connect to 'https:// website.com' on port 1234, without specifying port 1234, it wont work.  Maybe I don't understand your situation.

Comment: I have a reverse proxy for nzbget, couchpotato and sonarr. Since ATT hard programs their gateway to forward port 443 to their WAP, I am unable to forward it to my server. Port 80 forwards with no problem. I am new to revervse proxies. Since the reverse proxy can do a rewrite to port 443 wit https automatically, I don't understand why I can't just forward it to another port, whey does it have to be 443 for https to work without stipulating the port. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If your proxy can sit on 443 for external traffic, you can redirect that traffic to another port internally, like 8443, without specifying the port.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you get my problem. I just assume I can't do this. Port 443 is locked to a different device. If I try to create a new rule, it advises me 443 is already assigned. And I have no option to remove the current 443 port forward. Dam ATT

Comment: Yes, I understand.  My original assumption was correct.  A browser expects https to be on port 443, where you can't have it.  So unless your client specifies the port in the url, you can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any available port, but you'll have to use links like `https://host:port/file` only. Relative links like just `/file` are OK.

Also, I assume your router properly process the traffic, I have no idea what 'ATT Uverse' means :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another forum post similar to what you are asking. 
https://forums.att.com/t5/Features-and-How-To/Forwarding-port-443-for-WHS-conflict-with-connectToCiscoAP/td-p/3365983

Once you follow the above post, you can change your internal apache settings to listen on 4443 or whichever port you would chose to listen on for SSL traffic into your network.

```
<VirtualHost *:4443>
  ServerName youraddress.com
  #DocumentRoot /var/www/youraddress.com/htdocs

  #..
  #..

  # SSL configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/youraddress.com/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/youraddress.com/ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```